# How to use mathematical operation in char?

Tags: java, char

I am doing a credit card validation program( if you are unfamiliar with the method http://9gag.com/gag/70886/cracking-the-credit-card-code) , here is the link for it).
Problem is: when trying to to do operation "int multi" in the code, the int does not import   the real values of the credit card as proccessed by the charAt operation. how can I solve this, and what is it that I am doing wrong ? Also char does not allow math operations,  or does it ?

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreditCardCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream ps = System.out;
        int multi;

        System.out.println("Enter CreditCard number: ");
        String ccn  = sc.nextLine();

        if(ccn.length() < 16 || ccn.length() > 16 ){
            System.out.println("ccn is larger or less than 16-digits");//checking for 16-digit

        }else if(ccn.length() == 16){
            System.out.println("Validating CreditCard ");
        //multiplied numbers
        char zero = ccn.charAt(0);
        char second = ccn.charAt(2);
        char fourth = ccn.charAt(4);
        char sixth = ccn.charAt(6);
        char eight = ccn.charAt(8);
        char ten= ccn.charAt(10);
        char twelve = ccn.charAt(12);
        char fourteen = ccn.charAt(14);

        // added numbers

        char first = ccn.charAt(1);
        char third = ccn.charAt(3);
        char fifth= ccn.charAt(5);
        char seventh = ccn.charAt(7);
        char nineth = ccn.charAt(9);
        char eleven = ccn.charAt(11);
        char thirteen = ccn.charAt(13);
        char fifteen = ccn.charAt(15);

        //multiplication and addition
         multi = ((zero*2)+ first) + ((second*2)+third)
                + ((fourth*2)+ fifth) + ((sixth*2)+seventh) + ((eight*2)+nineth)
                + ((ten*2)+eleven)  + ((twelve*2)+thirteen) + ((fourteen*2)+fifteen);

        System.out.println(multi);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreditCardCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Sc`enter code here`anner(System.in);
        int multi;

        System.out.println("Enter CreditCard number: ");
        String ccn  = sc.nextLine();

        if(ccn.length() != 16 ){
            System.out.println("ccn is not equal to 16-digits");//checking for 16-digit
        }
        else if(ccn.length() == 16){
            System.out.println("Validating CreditCard ");

            //multiplied numbers
            int zero = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(0)+"");
            int second = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(2)+"");
            int fourth = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(4)+"");
            int sixth = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(6)+"");
            int eight = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(8)+"");
            int ten= Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(10)+"");
            int twelve = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(12)+"");
            int fourteen = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(14)+"");

            // added numbers
            int first = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(1)+"");
            int third = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(3)+"");
            int fifth= Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(5)+"");
            int seventh = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(7)+"");
            int nineth = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(9)+"");
            int eleven = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(11)+"");
            int thirteen = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(13)+"");
            int fifteen = Integer.parseInt(ccn.charAt(15)+"");

            //multiplication and addition
            multi = ((zero*2)+ first) + ((second*2)+third) + ((fourth*2)+ fifth) + ((sixth*2)+seventh) + ((eight*2)+nineth) + ((ten*2)+eleven)  + ((twelve*2)+thirteen) + ((fourteen*2)+fifteen);

            System.out.println(multi);
            System.out.println(zero);

        }
    }
}
```